# How a Table space for a query execution is chosen? - DB2

Tags: db2

For one of my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639962/sufficient-page-size-does-not-exist-db2-insert), I am trying to understand the functionalities of below DB2 entities,

- System Temporary table space.
- Page Size.
- Table Space.
- Buffer Pool.

And below is my observation,

- There is a ***TableSpace*** linked to a table in the DB2 table ***syscat.tables***
- The ***TableSpaces*** are linked to ***BufferPool*** with the relation defined in ***syscat.tablespaces***
- ***System Temporary table space*** is the table space that the DB might use while executing the query.
- ***Page Size*** is an unit that defines the limit of a ***TableSpace*** and says how much data can a ***TableSpace*** can hold.

Is there something wrong in my above understandings? And when I excute a query how does the DB chooses which ***TableSpace*** to choose?

Comment: Page size is not the limit of the tablespace. It is the minimum storage unit, and it defines the size of the row.

Comment: This is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603524/ibm-db2-9-7-determining-default-tablespace However, this does not apply for temporary tablespaces when DB has multiples in the same pagesize.